# Media query isn't stacking columns on mobile, but is applying other styling?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm having a bit of an issue with my media query (I'm new to using these, this is the "safest" way to render html emails responsive).

My media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.submitBtn {
margin: auto !important;
float: none !important;
}
td, h3, h4, .branding, .paragraph, .container {
display: block !important;
width: 100% !important;
float: none !important;
height: auto !important;
margin: auto !important;
padding: 0 !important;
text-align: center !important;
}
td {
padding-right: 5px !important;
padding-left: 5px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}
td.branding, img.branding {
display: block !important;
text-align: center !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.branding {
padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
.toggle {
text-align: left;
}
table.center {
text-align: center !important;
}
.display-none {
display: none !important;
}
.checkbox {
  display: block !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  float: none !important;
}
}
```

As a note, I do have the meta for device-width in the head. All other styling is rendering except where I have two td's, they are not stacking on mobile.

In chrome, using the inspector & setting it responsive, it shows they *should* be stacking on mobile but when I actually test it to myself they are not.

My first module that should be stacking (I put placeholders to remove sensitive data)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
       <td class="branding logo" width="315" align="left">Stacking image goes here
       </td>
        <td class="branding" width="315" align="right"><span class="lighter">Text & More</span> <span class="normal">Stacking text goes here</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My other bit that should be stacking:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" align="center">
                            <tr>
                              <td class="description" align="left" width="75%">
                                <h4 class="indent padding-t"><span class="normal middle"></span></h4>
                                <p class="paragraph indent">Y
                                </p>
                              </td>
                              <td class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="" onclick="changeValue()" value="">
                                <label class="toggle" for="checkbox"></label>
                                <input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="" checked value="">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
```

Thanks in advance for your help and I apologize if this is a "rookie" error because I'm about certain it is!

Comment: Not **everything** is `!important`. Remove them. They're not necessarily an will make overrides a real pain. It also looks like you're not designing for _"mobile first"_ and might be using tables for layout. In mobile-first design, the default styles are applied to the mobile view, not the desktop, and modified as needed for larger viewports.

Comment: @hungerstar yes, since it’s html email to ensure it renders properly across all email clients I have to use tables unfortunately. As for using important, the same thing seems to apply. When I remove it, the styling doesn’t apply.

Comment: I think that's accurate for email but not for the CSS. Looking at some of the [ZURB Email Templates](https://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates) CSS I don't see a lot of `!important`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the order of my css was messing everything up. I deleted all styling inside the media query and re-organized it and it works like a charm!